# npm start stops before the buildind and don't give any error

Tags: node.js, express

When I start my application through 'npm start' it starts building but it stops and doesn't show any error msg

I've left it runing for few hours but it doesn't build.

[application not building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqvux.png)

Comment: Post text, not images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your node.js app is perfectly running. Try putting a `console.log('Running!')` in your javascript file, and run it again. If you see the log in the console, it means everything is working correctly.

Please note: `npm start` does't make a "build" of your app, it just runs it. To build you app for production you should use `npm build`.

Comment: Thanks! I did it here and actually is working. It used to show a lot of other logs after that part, but now only shows that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! You've probably used some type of bundler or something before (like webpack), which does indeed show a lot of logs when it starts running. Glad you figured it out, could you accept my answer as the correct answer please?